# Repeated measure problem

Tags: repeated-measures, sas

I have 6 subjects. For each subject, we measured two variables over six-week period once a week. Let’s call the variables A and B. Variable A is binary (male or female), and variable B is continuous (blood pressure). Now I want to see if females have higher blood pressure than males. What kind of statistical method do you suggest here (keep in mind that we’re dealing with repeated measure)?

Comment: I'd suggest repeated measure ANOVA. But note that you have very small sample.

Comment: I would honestly just make a nice graph. It will probably tell as much of the story as there is to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to google "Analysis of Repeated Measures Data".

---

Let $y_{ij}$ be the $j$th continuous measurement ($j = 1, \dotsc, 6$) in subject $i$ ($i = 1, \dotsc, 6$). A linear model for $y_{ij}$ could be
$$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + e_{ij}, $$
where $\beta_0$ is an overall intercept, $x_i$ is the value of the binary variable in subject $i$, $\beta_1$ is the associated fixed effect parameter, and $e_{ij}$ is the error term assumed to come from a normal distribution with mean zero.

Due to the repeated measures, the error terms associated with the same subject are likely to be correlated. On the other hand, measures taken on two different subjects are usually independent. In other terms, the residual covariance matrix is a block diagonal matrix with one block for each subject, $\mathbf{R} = \textrm{diag}(\mathbf{R}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{R}_6)$. The $i$th block is given by
$$
\mathbf{R}_i = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\textrm{Var}(e_{i1}) & \textrm{Cov}(e_{i1}, e_{i2}) & \dotsc & \textrm{Cov}(e_{i1}, e_{i6}) \\
                     & \textrm{Var}(e_{i2})         & \dotsc & \textrm{Cov}(e_{i2}, e_{i6})
\\
                     &                              & \ddots & \vdots \\
                     &                              &        & \textrm{Var}(e_{i6})
\end{array}
\right).
$$

$$$$

Some structure can be put on $\mathbf{R}$. For example, following the AR(1) structure we have
$$
\mathbf{R}_i = \theta \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & \rho & \rho^2 & \dotsc & \rho^5 \\
  &  1   & \rho   & \dotsc & \rho^4 \\
  &      &  1     & \dotsc & \rho^3 \\
  &      &        & \ddots & \vdots       \\
  &      &        &        & 1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
with $\theta > 0$ and $0 < \rho < 1$. That is, the variance stays constant between any two measurements on the same subject, but the correlation decreases with the distance in time.

`SAS` provides a procedure that fits such a model: see the [documentation for proc mixed](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#mixed_toc.htm), and more particularly the `repeated` statement that is used to specify the $\mathbf{R}$ matrix. [Here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect031.htm) is an example.

Comment: Thank you ocram! What if I have the same problem as above, but instead of continuous variable I have a three-level discrete variable (high, medium, low). How this problem can be solved? Many thanks again!

Comment: You should NOT change blood pressure from a continuous variable to a discrete one.

Comment: @ocram that's a very thorough answer, but it may be more than what was requested. The question is just "do females have higher blood pressure than males?" this may be a case where simple is just as good as complex. But the repeated measures do allow more interesting questions to be asked.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your measurement is discreet, the answer is the same.  It might matter if your measurement was at best ordinal.  It would matter if your measurement was categorical.